# Bootstrap align label

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know if there was a way to align the text correctly to the input box. i'm using bootstrap. Ty

[IMAGE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nJPg.png)

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:62px">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Nome corso:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="form-inline">
  
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" style="height:62px">
     
        <label>Nome corso:</label>
     
     
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```